# Work done by gravitational force!

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy

Suppose a ball is $10m$ high from the ground. It will have $E_p = 10mg$. Now, if the ball falls freely then we know $E_k$ will be $0.5mv^2 = E_p$. But it is said that the work done by a force will transfer some energy to the forced object if the work is positive. Here work done by gravity will be positive. So the energy to the object should be $E_k = E_p$ (potential energy when it was up) $+ mgh$ ($F=mg$ and displacement is $h$) $= 2E_p$.

But it doesn't happen. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does indeed happen. The $mgh$ part, *is* the work done by gravity. Work done by a conservative force is "reversable" and can therefore be considered "stored". When you lift something to the clif, the work you do is *stored* as potential energy. And this energy is what the gravity can then use to do *work* on the object, as it falls.

More precisely, as gravity does work on an object, it can do up to $E_p$ of work on it. So when you set up the energy conservation equation where work done in this case equals the gain in kinetic energy

$$W=\Delta K=K_2-K_1$$

then this work $W$ equals the change in potential energy, so

$$-\Delta U=\Delta K$$

(The minus is because of the definition of work: $W=-\Delta U=-(U_2-U_1)=U_1-U_2$. Since the work done is positive, the potential energy loss must be positive too - and $U_1$ is bigger than $U_2$.)

What you call $E_p$ is the same as the work done by gravity. So $mgh$ should only appear once in your equation, and $E_k=E_p$, just as you say it should.

Comment: The work is not called potential energy. The work performed during a process is the difference in potential energy before and after.

Comment: @SebastianRiese Thank you, agreed. I have rewritten a bit and added some parts to clear this out.